# ARKit: Place a Node right behind a Node

Tags: swift, nodes, arkit

[image]

I want to put the red node right behind the blue node even after i change the position of iPhone.

(Please refer to the diagram)
When I start my AR App and tap the center of the screen to add the blue node, I get the blue node x,y,z axis and set the z axis of the red node a little bit further away. On this scenario my app behaves the way i expected.

The problem is when I rotate the iPhone, tap the screen to add the blue node, the red node seemed to be at the same depth like the initial state.

What i expected to have is when I add a blue node, always put the red node behind it (the blue node should always cover the red node the moment I add it)

Do anyone know how to do it?

I have this code to make the nodes always face the camera when i add them. but the position in space is kinda not the one I expected

```
//TAP THE SCREEN
let worldTransform = hitTestResultsWithFeaturePoint.worldTransform
let hitTransform = SCNMatrix4(worldTransform)
let hitVector = SCNVector3Make(hitTransform.m41, hitTransform.m42, hitTransform.m43)
let rotate = simd_float4x4(SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(sceneView.session.currentFrame!.camera.eulerAngles.y, 0, 1, 0))
let rotateTransform = simd_mul(worldTransform, rotate)

//ADD THE BLUE NODE
let bluenode = SCNNode()
bluenode.transform = SCNMatrix4(rotateTransform)
bluenode.position = SCNVector3(hitVector.x, hitVector.y, hitVector.z)

//ADD THE RED NODE BEHIND THE BLUE NODE
let rednode = SCNNode()
rednode.transform = SCNMatrix4(rotateTransform)
rednode.position = SCNVector3(hitVector.x, hitVector.y, hitVector.z - 0.05)
```

Comment: hack: place dots on an empty node, and empty node on scene. Or do maths to find transform along a line between camera and blue dot

Comment: would appreciate if theres some useful link or code to support your advice! but i appreciated you took time to write a comment :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the red node as a child of the blue one with coordinates to (0.0,0.0,-0.05) and then making the blue node face the camera with "[SCNBillboardConstraint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnbillboardconstraint)" should do the trick

Comment: adding the red node in the blue node works great! but making SCNBillboardConstraint with the blue node makes the red node follow the movement of the camera... what i wanted to do is when i place a blue node, at the exact back of it place red node and fix its position there

Comment: Yes, I probably misunderstood some details in your question, so it works by just adding the red as child of blue?

Comment: yes it works, but the moment i move the camera the red node moves with me

Comment: if both red and blue nodes are suposed to stay still exactly in the same place they where created and not to follow the camera you should use an ARAnchor to create the blue node and then make the red one "a child of the blue"

Comment: hmmm... ok i did some experiment and what i did was

Comment: oh sorry i didnt noticed that i posted incomplete text. Btw, I did

bluenode.getNode().transform = sceneView.pointOfView!.transform

then add the red node in the blue node then I offset the red node's z position. since you gave me idea i will accept your answer

Comment: btw i have another question here. if you have any idea please teach me

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51015711/arkit-plot-a-node-at-a-specific-pixel-at-a-specific-z-distance-from-camera

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution, happy to know I helped a bit, I've read your other post an will return with a suggestion soon